# Seams appear in blender but not in substance painter. Something to do with directX normal maps

Tags: normal-map, seams

The top of my mesh from SB:
[image]

Top of my mesh from Blender:
[image]

Looking closely, it looks like there is a misalignment... Substance painter has DirectX normal maps and OpenGL normal maps.  When I use the latter, it works just fine, so I'm guessing this has something to do with directX and Evee.  Perhaps there is a switch I should be turning on?

Top of my mesh in blender after exporting OpenGL normal maps

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL uses Y+ for it's normal calculations (first pixel at bottom going "up") whereas DirectX uses Y- (first pixel at top going "down"). Here is the method for DirectX to OpenGL conversion for normal maps that "flips" them to the correct orientation (if it helps):

[image: DirextXtoOPenGL]

NOTE - The setup above can also be also be accomplished by using an *Invert Node* on the Y (Green channel) instead of the Math node, however this would convert greyscale to color then back to greyscale again - the math node keeps it non-color throughout - probably not important for this project but for very large projects, this method is (*very slightly*) faster.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to figure out the same method earlier.